# dimension of the set of all real functions differentiable at a point

Tags: vector-spaces

A problem from chapter 1 of Millman and Parker's Elements of Differential Geometry:

Let $D_5=\{f:R \rightarrow R\ |\ f'\mbox{ is differentiable at } 5\}$. What is $\dim(D_5)$?

I'm basically certain $D_5$ has infinite dimension, but am struggling to find an argument that only uses the definition of a vector space, linear independence, basis, and dimension. The two arguments I have been able to think of use theorems I learned from previous linear algebra courses:

first argument,

we know $P=\{\mbox{all polynomials from } \mathbb{R}\mbox{ to } \mathbb{R}\}$ has infinite dimension and we know $P\subset D_5$ so we must have $\dim(P)\leq \dim(D_5)$.

second argument,

if $\dim(D_5) = n$ is finite then $X=\{0,x,x^2,...,x^{n-1}\}$ must be a basis for $D_5$ but $x^n \in D_5$ so X can't be a basis for $D_5$.

What would a reasonable (in terms of complexity) argument be that uses just the few definitions I listed?

Comment: Both arguments you give work fine, except you shouldn't include $0$ in your $X$ as otherwise $X$ is not linearly independent.  Instead use $X=\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}$.  You're going to have to use something about differentiability here, and this seems like a pretty minimal amount to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of considering $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ is good, but not in the direction you seem to be trying.

You can prove that the set of functions $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ is contained in $D_5$ and is linearly independent for each $n$. Thus the space cannot be finite dimensional.

Why is it linearly independent? Because two polynomials are equal if and only if all their coefficients are equal.

Comment: I see, thanks. And we know that this argument about polynomials suffices for all of $D_5$ because if we had some non-polynomial functions that could generate polynomials then P wouldn't be a vector space. Correct?

Comment: @aaachilless It just suffices to show that $D_5$ contains an infinite dimensional subspace, because all subspaces of a finite dimensional space are finite dimensional.